# Creating folders using Android SDK

Tags: android, shell, sdk, adb

Is it possible to be able to create a folder on the sd card of the phone via using Android SDK or the Shell?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mkdir /sdcard/newfolder` in an exec/shell.